# Copy data from a sheet to a new workbook with dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy data from one sheet to a new workbook with a dynamic range that finds the last empty row with vba. I managed to make that work but I couldn't make it not check for formulas in the cell. So I need to find a way to make it stop copying if cell is empty or with formula.

```
Sub CopyUserDataPROD()
  Dim CopyLastRow As Long
  
  Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
  Set wsCopy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UL users PROD")
  
  CopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
  wsCopy.Range("A1:AJ" & CopyLastRow).Copy
  NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain more detailed what you mean by *"I couldn't make it not check for formulas in the cell"*? It is very unclear (at least to me) what exactly you are trying to do. Can you give an example?

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation. I am trying to copy all the fields that are filled in a sheet into a new workbook. The numbers of rows filled can vary and that is why i need the copied range to be dynamic. With the code i wrote above i check if the cells in column B are filled, if yes the whole row is copied, if not it stops. The problem is that some cells might have a formula and my code understands that as data and copies everything. I need it to stop copying the cell is empty or contains a formula.

Is that a bit more clear?

Comment: This `wsCopy.Range("A1:AJ" & CopyLastRow).Copy` copies all cells in the given range **at once**, no matter what they contain. If you want to check for formulas or something you need to loop through your range and check each row individually and copy each row individually. Since we have no idea how your data actually looks like we cannot give a more detailed answer.